# Can we use multiple Flurry ids in one app?

Tags: android, flurry

Can we use multiple Flurry ids in one app?
I have a separate module with its own activites, which uses Flurry and has its own Flurry app id.

And I integrated this module to my app, which uses Flurry as well, with its own Flurry app id too.

My app can start activities from that module, and when they are finished, continue again.

Won't this break Flurry normal workflow?

Comment: Not according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308072/is-it-possible-to-use-several-flurry-api-keys-in-the-same-ios-application