# It's possible to start two difference flurry sessions in one activity?

Tags: android, session, flurry, flurry-analytics

I create two *applications* on Yahoo Flurry, and I want it to get events from one android app.
When i try to call:

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, getResources().getString(R.string.flury_project_api_key));
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, getResources().getString(R.string.flury_android_api_key));
```

in logcat i see

> 10-07 14:07:09.559 29425-29443/? W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session
>   started for context:com.package.ActivityName@d6930fe
>
> 10-07 14:07:09.559 29425-29443/? W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session
>   resumed for   context:com.package.ActivityName@d6930fe

and only one *application* on flurry, which key is `flury_project_api_key`, receive all events from app.

On SO i found just this question [Can we use multiple Flurry ids in one app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090817/can-we-use-multiple-flurry-ids-in-one-app) without answers.

Answer (score 0):

An App can only run one Activity at the same time. MAybe Im wrong but Im assuming you want two Activities be run at same time from one app

Edit:

Second Try:

See Documentation:

" So long as there is any Context that has called onStartSession(Context) but not onEndSession(Context), the session will be continued. Also, if a new Context calls onStartSession(Context) within 10 seconds (the default session timeout length) of the last Context calling onEndSession, then the session will be resumed, instead of a new session being created."

Comment: Look's like you you don't understand question. Maybe because my english is bad.

I have one activity. And it's work perfect. In this activity i try to start two flurry sessions. With difference ids. And then i try post event to two difference flurry applications. But only one application receive all events. 
Question: it's possible to post flurry events from one activity to multiple flurry applications with difference flurry ids ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the changelog starting from Flurry SDK 5.x there is no need to call start session / end session anymore. The SDK will detect it automatically.