# Is it possible to use several Flurry API keys in the same IOS application

Tags: ios, flurry

I am building an application which has two flavors - branded and not branded (general app store version). I want to get all version analytic data to one account but for the branded applications I also want to allow the customer to have his own analytic account. What I am thinking about is duplicating every Flurry call in the branded apps, so it will also report data to the customer custom account (which will be configured when the branded app will be deployed).

Does someone have any experience with similar setups or a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to have multiple Flurry sessions running in the same app. So there is not a way to have the analytic data report to more than one api key.

You can allow 3rd parties limited access to your account. For instance you can allow them to see data for only one project. Have a look at the Admin -> Users section of the Flurry dev portal to set this up.

I would suggest creating a separate api key for each instance of the branded app, and give users access to only that app in Flurry. You will still be able to aggregate the metrics of all these instances using the app grouping features.

If there will be many (ie thousands) of users and projects this may not scale well, but otherwise this is a reasonable approach.